# jqueryui tabs reload on every select

Tags: jquery, tabs, reload

Every tiem I select a tab, the tab reload all the contents and loses all the content of the forms etc...

Any idea where I should look to solve this?

thanks,
Jas

Comment: Could you give some code example please

Comment: way too big... I guess I'll try and isolate it down first.

Answer (score 2):

However it is an old problem but the solution is set cache true:

```
$(function() {
  $('selector').tabs({
    cache: true
  });
});
```